# Vega chart: how to hide 0 values from the chart, but keep info on the axes?

Tags: charts, filtering, vega

I have vega charts.
When zeroes are coming, it shows chart this way:

[image]

Is it possible to remove circles when value is equal to 0?
I tried to filter the data by data.filter(el=>el.count!==0), but it also removes the values on X-axis.

[image]

I need to keep the values, but remove circles only.
Also tried to use "transform" in vega spec, but is does not show anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [production rules](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/marks/#production-rules) to set opacity to `0` when value is equal to zero and to `1` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

`data.filter(el=>el.count!==0)` is not showing any circles. Because y-axis value for all circles from first picture shows the value as 0.

To remove the circle that overlaps with y-axis, `data.filter(el => el.date != first_date_value)` would remove the first circle from left.`first_date_value` is the minimum date starting on x-axis.

To do it in vega way, move the x-axis by same amount of pixels as radius of circle. So, the x-axis scale would be of range `[radius_of_circle, width]` instead of `[0, width]`

```
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "x",
      "type": "point",
      "range": {"signal": "[15, width]"},
      "domain": {"data": "table", "field": "x"}
    },
...
```

This would start the x-axis with a 15px offset like below image. Thereby, even the first circle does not overlap on y-axis.

[image]